# Live Streaming over HTTP using CloudFront and FFMPEG having delay issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

Live Streaming using CloudFront and FFMPEG having delay issue I am using the NodeJS server with FFMPEG and live streaming to CloudFront, which is then consumed by many people via CloudFront. Below is the data received at the user's end.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1317
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:1
#EXTINF:0.833333,
1317.ts
#EXTINF:0.833333,
1318.ts
#EXTINF:0.833333,
1319.ts
```

The problem is the next .ts file that is 1320.ts is taking time to create on the server, thus the user is seeing the loading sign, and when this 1320.ts is created on the server, thereafter only the user is able to see the next live stream frame. How can the streaming be continuous?? Below is the FFMPEG command that is being used:

```
process = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', commandArgs);
```

```
let commandArgs = [
  '-loglevel',
  'debug',
  '-protocol_whitelist',
  'pipe,udp,rtp,rtmp,http,https,tcp',
  '-fflags',
  '+genpts',
  '-f',
  'sdp',
  '-i',
  'pipe:0',
  '-c:v',
  'libx264',
  '-crf',
  '21',
  '-preset',
  'veryfast',
  '-g',
  '25',
  '-sc_threshold',
  '0',
  '-c:a',
  'aac',
  '-b:a',
  '128k',
  '-ac',
  '2',
  '-hls_flags',
  'delete_segments+append_list',
  '-f',
  'segment',
  '-segment_list_flags',
  'live',
  '-segment_time',
  '1',
  '-segment_list_size',
  '3',
  '-segment_format',
  'mpegts',
  '-segment_list',
  `${RECORD_FILE_LOCATION_PATH}/${fileName}.m3u8`,
  `-segment_list_type`,
  'm3u8',
  `${RECORD_FILE_LOCATION_PATH}/%d.ts`
];
```